# How a program can know which method use (polymorphism)

Tags: java

I have two classes 
First class named *Myclass* This is the parent class

```
public class Myclass {
    public  static int x = 10;

     static void printX() {
         System.out.println("From the Superclass x = " + x);
    }
}
```

Second class named *MySecondClass* *This the child class*

```
public class MySecondClass extends Myclass   {
    static void printX() {
       System.out.print("From the Subclass x = " + x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printX();
    }
}
```

As a newbie in Java Programming, I want to understand the Polymorphism; How can it choose between the two methods `printX()`? And in the code above why does it choose the `MySecondClass` method ?

Comment: static method cannot be overridden in Java.

Comment: There is no polymorphism here, since your methods are static. printX() is equivalent to MySecondClass.printX(), because the code is inside MySecondClass. You know it by learning the rules of the language.

Comment: @dassum , Thank you ! some more clarifications ? please

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you ! nice explained :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If methods are static, then it is determined at compile time which method is called, based on the class involved in the call.

If methods are instance members, then the relevant method body is looked up by its signature on the instance's concrete class, at runtime, falling back progressively upward on super classes until found. Consider that a simple map of signature-to-functionpointer, in each class and super classes, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community.

What you are trying to do here is called overriding. Although in reality java does not allow static methods to be overridden.  If you instantiate the child class and call "printX" it will call the overridden method in the child class.

IE:  From the Subclass x = .

But if you instantiate the parent class and call the method it will print "From the Superclass"

Although in this scenario what you are doing is not "overriding" as the methods are static. But this approach is called "method hiding"

To answer your question, it chose the second method because the second method (child class method) has hidden your super class method.

Comment: Thank you men for the welcome ... yeah i see my fault